# Creating XML without encoding attribute in prolog using XmlLite IXmlWriter (C++)

Tags: c++, xmlwriter, xmllite

I am using the XmlLite library to create an XML file. I want the resulting XML file's prolog to not include the encoding attribute (just the version):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Here is my code:

```
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IStream *pOutFileStream = NULL;
    IXmlWriter *pWriter = NULL;
    CComPtr<IXmlWriterOutput> pWriterOutput;

    //Open writeable output stream
    if (FAILED(hr = SHCreateStreamOnFile(output_file_name, STGM_CREATE | STGM_WRITE, &pOutFileStream)))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error creating file writer, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = CreateXmlWriter(__uuidof(IXmlWriter), (void**) &pWriter, NULL)))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error creating xml writer, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }

    if(FAILED(CreateXmlWriterOutputWithEncodingName(pOutFileStream, NULL, L"UTF-8", &pWriterOutput))){
        wprintf(L"Error setting xml encoding, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pWriter->SetOutput(pWriterOutput)))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error, Method: SetOutput, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pWriter->SetProperty(XmlWriterProperty_Indent, 4)))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error, Method: SetProperty XmlWriterProperty_Indent, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pWriter->WriteStartDocument(XmlStandalone_Omit)))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error, Method: WriteStartDocument, error is %08.8lx", hr);
        HR(hr);
    }
```

I have tried removing the call to `CreateXmlWriterOutputWithEncodingName()` but even then a default encoding attribute with UTF-8 is getting created.
I have also tried putting `NULL` as the third parameter to that function.

Assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML declaration is written by the [`WriteStartDocument` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Instead of calling `WriteStartDocument`, you can call [`WriteProcessingInstruction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `L"xml"` as the name of the processing instruction to write the XML declaration the way you want, for example:

```
if (FAILED(hr = pWriter->WriteProcessingInstruction(L"xml", L"version=\"1.0\"")))
{
    wprintf(L"Error, Method: WriteProcessingInstruction, error is %08.8lx", hr); 
    HR(hr); 
}
```

This will write the XML declaration as `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.